# cannot assign values to variables

Tags: javascript

The agent and other variables inside else if (linux) statement are showing as undefined. This code works in all other os except linux. However I am able to assign values in console.

```
function detectoperatingsystem()
 {
    var agent = navigator.userAgent;
    if(/Windows NT (\d+\.\d)/i.test(agent))
    {
        self.osType = "windows";
        self.osTypeDisplay = "Windows";
        self.osVersion = (RegExp.$1).toString();
        configureWindowsVersionDisplay(agent);
    }
    else if(/iP(?:(?:hone)|(?:ad))/i.test(agent))
    {
        self.osType = "iPhone";
        self.osTypeDisplay = "IOS";
        self.isIOS = true;
        configureIOSVersionAndDisplay(agent);
    }
    else if (/Android (\d+\.\d)/i.test(agent)) {
        if (agent.indexOf("Mobile") !== -1)
        {
            self.osType = "AndroidPhone";
            self.osTypeDisplay = "AndroidPhone";
        }
        else
        {
            self.osType = "Android";
            self.osTypeDisplay = "Android";
        }
        self.isAndroid = true;
        self.osVersion = self.osVersionDisplay = RegExp.$1;
    }
    else if(/linux/i.test(agent))
    {
        self.osType = "Linux";
        self.osTypeDisplay = "Linux";
        self.osVersion = 1;
        self.osVersionDisplay = "";
    }
    else
    {
        self.osType = "Unknown";
        self.osVersion = "Unknown";
    }
}
```

Comment: what is `self` in your code?

Comment: change self for this

Comment: this is a closure and self stands for this in my function

Comment: What string do you get back from navigator.userAgent for Linux?

Comment: @fdfey , I guess problem is not with self as agent is not taking any value

Comment: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0  -- @ManoDestra

Comment: Can't replicate your issue. Must be something to do with the self reference in your OS/Browser combo. I've tried amending the string to specifically be the one you supplied and it works fine (on Windows using Firefox). The values are written accordingly.

Comment: thank you, I am facing problem only with linux

Comment: Are you actually certain you're hitting the `linux` block?

Comment: @nrabinowitz- in linux and chrome agent is not taking any value so statement jumps to else block. in firefox and linux  agent was assigned a value and jumps to linux block. but no variable gets the value and finally statement again jumps to else block.